# Two different ways of handling the form Close event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a *Save* button on my `WinForm` which saves the form information and then closes the form using the `this.Close()` statement.

There is however another way of closing the form and that is the `X` button.

I am using the `FormClosing` event to ask a question before the form is closed.

```
private void EmailNewsletter_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MsgBox.Show("Are you sure you want to dimiss this newsletter?", "Dismiss Newsletter", MsgBox.Buttons.YesNo, MsgBox.Icon.Question);
    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Newsletter = null;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But the way of handling the close form depends on how the form is closed. If the user clicks on the *Save* button, the form should be closed without a question. It is only when user clicks on the `X` button that the question should be asked.

How can I let my form know what the *Close* command comes from?

Comment: use variable "isFromSaveButton"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple boolean flag should do the trick:

```
private bool saveClicked = false;
private void btnSave_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      saveClicked = true;
}
private void EmailNewsletter_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(saveClicked)
         return;

    DialogResult dr = MsgBox.Show("Are you sure you want to dimiss this newsletter?", "Dismiss Newsletter", MsgBox.Buttons.YesNo, MsgBox.Icon.Question);

    if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Newsletter = null;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! will be accepted as answer in 5 minutes because I upped you!